# "$.options is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I am using mana Pro Plugin for magento but i think this is just a javascript / jquery issue.

I have two partially built stores:

http://wvgear.ohabash.sp-dev.us/audio-downloads.html?speaker_name=1277

http://shopnerium.ohabash.sp-dev.us/apparel.html?m-layered=1&size_hats=22&m-layered=1

Shopnerium shows and error when trying to load the plugin's options, preventing me from making ajax work:

```
"$.options is not a function"
```

while both are seemingly set up the same; wvgear does not have the error and the plugin works as expected.

Why does shopnerium show the console error but wvgear does not.

Comment: Your `$` is Prototype, not jQuery. You should use `jQuery.options` instead, or enclose it noConflict mode e.g. `(function($) { $.options... })(jQuery);`

Comment: it was too big of a script to put in this post; but jquery was set up just the way you described above